# create a function jade

Tags: node.js, function, express, pug

I would like to create a function in jade but I cant' find how

I found something in the javadoc about finctions https://github.com/visionmedia/jade ,but I don't understand

I would like to try if a variable exist if not return the var name, a little like this php script:

```
function vname(&$var, $scope=false, $prefix='unique', $suffix='value')
{
    if($scope) $vals = $scope;
    else      $vals = $GLOBALS;
    $old = $var;
    $var = $new = $prefix.rand().$suffix;
    $vname = FALSE;
    foreach($vals as $key => $val) {
        if($val === $new) $vname = $key;
    }
    $var = $old;
    return $vname;
 }
 if(!isset($var)){echo vname($var)}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically comes down to adding a function to the locals object. You can do this in a few different places.

Route:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.locals.someFunction = function () { /* do stuff */ };
});
```

General Middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.someFunction = function () { /* do stuff */ };
  next();
});
```

Application:

```
app.locals.someFunction = function () { /* do stuff */ };
```

Is this super basic stuff and is normally documented on the Express.js website.